# Unique email check in zend framework is not working properly

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am working on a project based on Zend framework. In user registration I have to check for unique email. My code is working fine when I register a user for the first time, but when I try to update the user information and press the update button, it gives the error message:

```
Email already taken
```

Please help me to solve this problem. My code is attached below:

```
$this->addElement('text', 'email', array(
                'label'      => 'Your email address:',
                'required'   => true,
                'filters'    => array('StringTrim'),
                'validators' => array(
                        'EmailAddress',
                        array('Db_NoRecordExists', true, array(
                                'table' => 'users',
                                'field' => 'email',
                                'messages' => array(
                                        'recordFound' => 'Email already taken'
                                )
                        )
                        )
                )
        ));
```

I have changed my controller to this:

```
public function addAction()
    {
        $modelUsers = new Model_Users();
        $userId = $this->_getParam('userId');
        $form = $this->_getAddForm();

        if ($userId) {              
            $populateData = array();

            $user = $modelUsers->fetch($userId);

            if ($user instanceof Model_User) {
                $populateData = $user->toArray();
            }

            $form->populate($populateData);
        }

        $request = $this->getRequest();

        if ($request->isPost()) {
            $email = $this->getRequest()->getParam('email');
            if (strtolower(trim($email)) == $modelUsers->fetchByEmail($email)) {
                // change $this->_user->getAccount()->getEmail() to retrieve the user's current email address

                // remove validator from form
                $form->getElement('email')->removeValidator('Db_NoRecordExists');
            }

            $post = $request->getPost();

            if ($form->isValid($post)) {
                $values = $form->getValidValues($post);
                $data = array(
                    'firstName'     => $values['firstName'],
                    'userTypeId'    => 2,
                    'lastName'      => $values['lastName'],
                    'email'         => $values['email'],
                    'userName'      => $values['userName'],
                    'password'      => $values['password'],
                    'role'          => $values['role']
                );

                if ($userId) {
                    $user = $modelUsers->fetch($userId);
                    if ($user instanceof Model_User) {
                        $user->setFromArray($data);
                        $success = $user->save();
                        if ($success) {
                            echo Zend_Json::encode(array('status' => self::STATUS_SUCCESS, 'message' => 'Successfully updated the user!'));
                            exit;
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    $user = $modelUsers->createRow($data);
                    $success = $user->save();
                    if ($success) {
                        echo Zend_Json::encode(array('status' => self::STATUS_SUCCESS, 'message' => 'Successfully added the user!'));
                        exit;
                    }

                }
                echo Zend_Json::encode(array('status' => self::STATUS_FAILED, 'message' => 'user not added'));
                exit;               
            } else {

                $errors = array();
                $errors = $form->errors();              

                echo Zend_Json::encode(array('status' => self::STATUS_ERROR, 'data' => $errors));
                exit;

            }
        }

        $this->view->form = $form;
        $this->_helper->layout->disableLayout();

    }
```

Model:

```
public function fetchByEmail($email)
{
    $email=fetchOne('SELECT email FROM users WHERE email = $email');
    //$select->where('email=?',$email) ;
    //$student = $this->fetchRow($select);
    return $email;
}
```

But still this is not working

Comment: where exactly does `$userId` come from?

Comment: I want to write custom validator class for that. But I don't know exactly how to do this :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One simple way you can solve this problem is to remove the validator from that form element when the form is being edited.  You may also want to keep the validator if they are attempting to change their email address since they shouldn't be able to change their email to one that already exists in the database.

Leave the validator in your `Zend_Form` class, add this code *only when a user is being edited*.

```
if ($this->getRequest->isPost()) {
    $email = $this->getRequest()->getParam('email'); // get email from form

    // if email address has not changed, remove validator from form
    if (strtolower(trim($email)) == $this->_user->getAccount()->getEmail()) {
       // change $this->_user->getAccount()->getEmail() to retrieve the user's current email address

       // remove validator from form
       $form->getElement('email')->removeValidator('Db_NoRecordExists');
    }

    // validate form
    if ($form->isValid($this->getRequest()->getPost()) {
        //...
    }
}
```

So what you are doing is removing the `Db_NoRecordExists` validator from the form element when the form is being edited, and only if they are not attempting to change their email address if they are allowed to do so.

Comment: I have tried your solution. But it's not working. I attached code with the post. Thanks

Comment: Is it not working because the validator isn't being removed or do you get a different error?  I don't think your fetchByEmail method will work.  If they are changing their email this won't have the desired effect.  If the user is already logged in, get their email by their ID not by the email coming from the form.

Answer (score 1):

It will give you allways this error because you are using validation , that email is present in DB table or not.

But the email is existing in database that's why it is giving error.

Remove this validation , it will help you.

```
if(isset($_SESSION['session_id']))
{
     // code for update query
}
else
{
     // code for insert query
}
```

Comment: I can't remove the validation. Duplicate entry of email is not allowed

Comment: when you use insert statement at that time only use validation, on updating don't use validation.

Comment: Then I have to use two different forms. One for insert and one for update. Isn't it?

Comment: try to use flag for this (insert and update) rather than creating new forms for both.

Comment: I don't know how to use flag. Can you provide me a sample code of using flag.

Comment: I am trying this in a different way. If it works I will share the code.

Thanks